# jQuery Colorbox totally contracts on ajax image fetch

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I'm using the jQuery colorbox to should secondary product images from my products page. (If you are at work this is a fancy dress website so expect cop uniforms etc).

The colorbox incorporates an ajax page which is basically the secondary product image that is fetched from the database.

If however, the image takes a little time to get, the colorbox totally contracts and doesnt show anything.

If you request it again, it then works fine.

E.g. Using the page that follows click on any of the 2 smaller secondary images for the product: http://test.naughtyfancydress.com/Costumes/christmas-sparkle-dress-by-fever-523

Comment: I should also mention that I am specifying a height on the image but not a width as this might not always be the same but I wanted the height at a set limit.

Comment: example code might be nice.  You could be implementing colorbox improperly.

Comment: Thank you for your response, however, colorbox definitely was implemented correctly as it works elsewhere and on the second click in the same area. No need to paste code when the url to the page above. I have anyway resolved the issue, see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite the solution i wanted.

But I removed the ajax load colorbox to be replaced with a hidden div which is shown in the colorbox when needed.